# Why isn't my recursive function returning the final result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have a method which traverses an nested object recursively until it finds a matching folder name:

```
findSpecifiedFolder(data) {
    const bookmarks = JSON.parse(data).roots.bookmark_bar.children;
    const search = bookmarks => {
        for(let folder of bookmarks) {
            const folderName = folder.name.toLowerCase();
            if(folderName === folderArg.toLowerCase()) {
                console.log(folder); // returns folder object
                return folder // never returns anything
            }
            else if(folder.children) {
                search(folder.children);
            }
        }
    };
    search(bookmarks);
}
```

So by using `console.log` and my debugger I can see the following:

1. The method does, in fact recursively search the given object, nested at least 3 levels deep.
2. I can confirm that I do in fact have a successful check when `if(folderName === folderArg.toLowerCase())` gets executed both via the `console.log` statement and the data in the debugger

However, the return statement isn't getting executed (confirmed with debugger) and the method returns undefined (or an error when I called by another method with error logging). I no idea why so here I am asking if anyone might see some mistake in the method that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the recursive call, or else the returned value will not be delegated and returned when all recursive calls are resolved:

```
else if(folder.children) {
    return search(folder.children);
}
```

A simple proof of concept is the Fibonacci sequence. Here's some pseudocode (without return):

```
function fib(n) {
    if n is 1 return 0;
    else if n is 2 return 1;
    else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

So if I call `fib(2)`, it will go through the following execution steps:

1. Go to else
2. Call `fib(1)`
3. Return 0
4. Call `fib(2)`
5. Return 1
6. Add `0 + 1`
7. Then do nothing. The code is basically `else 1;` which is an expression (the `1` part) and does nothing.

Since there is no `return`, the final result is computed, but you do nothing with it and the function returns undefined. You have to *return* it. The same principle applies here.

Comment: This works and with your fib example I now get why it works - thanks for explaining it!

Comment: @HelloWorld No problem, glad to help!